# Spurious 'variable is never used' warning?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to clean up my code to get rid of Kotlin warnings, but I don't understand what's causing a couple warnings- I have this code:

```
var slowestMps:Float? = null
for (r in this.sections.subList(i + 1, this.sections.size - 1)) {
    if (!r.locs.any { l -> l.speed <= this.maxReversePointMps}) {
        continue
    }

    val mps = r.m / r.s
    if (slowest == null || (slowestMps != null && mps < slowestMps)) {
        slowest = r
        slowestMps = mps
    }
}
```

And I get the warnings:

```
Variable 'slowestMps' is never used
The value 'mps' assigned to 'var slowestMps: Float? defined in ... is never used
```

Why are these warnings getting triggered - aren't these variables being used?

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? I can only think this is a bug of the compiler...

Comment: @Augusto currently on 1.3.41...

Comment: @Augusto - looks like you were right - 1.3.72 doesn't trigger these.

Comment: Glad to hear it's *fixed* :D - I **love** kotlin, but the compiler still has some interesting issues and regressions that pop every now and then. Luckily JetBrains & the community are incredibly quick to fix them.